# Query is too slow, and not using index

Tags: mysql

here is the "explain" of my query:

```sql
explain
select eil.sell_fmt, count(sell_fmt)  as itemCount 
from table_items eil  
where eil.cl_Id=123 and eil.si_Id='0' 
  and start_date <= now() and end_date is not null and end_date < NOW() 
group by eil.sell_fmt
```

without date (start_date, end_date) filters:

```
id  select_type table   type            possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      eil ref                 table_items_clid_siid_sellFmt   39      const,const 7393    Using where; Using index
```

With date filters:

```
id  select_type table   type            possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      eil ref                 table_items_clid_siid_sellFmt   39      const,const 8400    Using where
```

possible_keys are:

```
table_items_clid_siid, table_items_clid_siid_itemId, table_items_clid_siid_startDate_endDate, table_items_clid_siid_sellFmt
```

The query without date filters is very fast (0.4 sec), but with date filters, its taking about 30 seconds. total records are 14K only.

Table field types:

```
`cl_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`si_Id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`sell_fmt` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
```

I concatenated field-names to give index names, so you can estimate combined fields available in the index.

Can somebody guide me here? what's going on here? what is the best course of action i should take here, or where i'm doing wrong?

---

**I need one more suggestio**n: in another query on same table, a user can filter based on UPTO 10 fields, and in no definite order of fields (random no of fields in random order). Then this type search would be too slow again. What's the best strategy then? one covering index with "all" possible searchable fields? if yes, does the order of fields in index matter? (i.e. if that order is different than that of fields in query, will the index be used?

Comment: could you please post the create table statement ?

Comment: is it ever possible in your setup that `start_date` exceeds the `end_date`?

Comment: Is this really a table of 14k rows? Or the query returns 14k rows?

Comment: table currently have total 14k rows only, and the query should match some 10.5k.  start-date should be less than end-date, though end-date can be null for some records even when start-date have a value. But it'd be interesting to know how does the values of date fields affect the query performance, or the choice of index/index-fields etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, without seeing your create table statement, I can offer the following... create composite index (multiple fields) that best match your common querying elements applicable to the where clause, starting with the smaller nominal count basis.  Since you are explicitly looking for a "cl_ID" and "si_ID" plus start and end dates.  Since you have a group by, I would add that to the index for optimization purposes and be a completely COVERING index so the engine does not need to go back to the raw data to complete the query.  It can resolve by all fields in the index directly.

I would have an index on

```
( cl_id, si_id, start_date, end_date, sell_fmt )
```

Finally, change your count from count(sell_fmt) to just count(*) indicating an "i don't care about a specific field, just as long as a record is found, count it"

Comment: Thank you. I had read about covering index, and had created multiple indexes, obviously which didn't include all the fields involved.